# Was bedeutet "verwindungsfrei in Waage und in der Flucht"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, german-to-english, technical-terminology

Ich habe diesen Satz in einer Betriebsanleitung einer Maschine gefunden. Es wurde im Zusammenhang mit dem Absetzung der Maschine erwähnt.

Hier der ganze Satz:

*Nachdem Sie die Maschine positioniert haben, richten Sie diese vollständig verwindungsfrei in Waage und in der Flucht zu der geforderten Ein- und Auslaufhöhe aus!*

Es wäre gut, wenn ihr auch die englische Übersetzung hier geben könntet.

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch? (Mein Lieblingssatz!)

Answer (score 2):

- **verwindungsfrei**
  torsion-free
- **in Waage**
  balanced
- **in Flucht ausrichten**
  align

Sogar der [Google-Übersetzer](https://translate.google.at/?hl=de&tab=wT#de/en/Nachdem%20Sie%20die%20Maschine%20positioniert%20haben%2C%20richten%20Sie%20diese%20vollst%C3%A4ndig%20verwindungsfrei%20in%20Waage%20und%20in%20der%20Flucht%20zu%20der%20geforderten%20Ein-%20und%20Auslaufh%C3%B6he%20aus!) kann diesen Satz ziemlich verständlich ins Englische übersetzen:

> After you have positioned the machine, align it completely in the balance and in alignment with the required inlet and outlet height!

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt:

> After positioning the machine, align it horizontally without distortion and to the required height for entry and outlet.

So "verwindungsfrei" is "without distortion", "in Waage" means "horizontally" in both directions of the floor and "in der Flucht" is "aligned" with the connections.